# SQL-linking two tables with a third table

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I have two tables **Students** and **Courses**.

I have to create a mapping table to link these two tables with a set of information.
For eg: Mary Murphy from **Students ** table is to be linked with **Courses** table with web designing course that she is taking.

How can I do this??
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You would use a third table, `studentCourses` would be a reasonable name.  It would look something like this:

```
create table studentCourses (
    studentCourseId int auto_increment primary key,
    studentId int,
    courseId int,
    constraint fk_studentcourses_student foreign key (studentId) references students (studentId),
    constraint fk_studentcourses_course foreign key (courseId) references students (courseId)
);
```

You might include other information, such as the enrollment date.